# Como implementar Click Listener al RecyclerView?

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

Tengo una base de datos en Firebase donde subo texto que luego recupero en el `RecyclerView` como items, lo que nececesito es que al tocar un `item` del `recyclerview` pueda pasar esos datos a otra `activity`.

**Mi Adaptador**

```
public class MyAdaptador extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdaptador.ViewHolder>{



private Context context;
private List<Upload> uploads;



public MyAdaptador(Context context, List<Upload> uploads) {

    this.uploads = uploads;
    this.context = context;



}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cuadros_de_textos, parent, false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);



    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {


    Upload upload = uploads.get(position);

    holder.titulo.setText(upload.getTitulo());

    holder.texto.setText(upload.getTexto());





}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return uploads.size();
}



public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView titulo;
    public TextView texto;




    public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        

        titulo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.titulo_del_cuadro);
        texto = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.texto_del_cuadro);



      

    }


   }




 }
```

**MainActivy donde recibo los datos en el Recyclerview**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {



//recyclerview object
private RecyclerView recyclerView;

//adapter object
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

//database reference
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

//progress dialog
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

//list to hold all the uploaded images
private List<Upload> uploads;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.DATABASE_PATH_UPLOADS);





    floatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.floatingbotton);

    floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CreateNote.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    GridLayoutManager mGridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 2);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mGridLayoutManager);


    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);


    uploads = new ArrayList<>();


    //displaying progress dialog while fetching images
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    progressDialog.show();


    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.DATABASE_PATH_UPLOADS);


    //adding an event listener to fetch values
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {



            //Detener the progress dialog
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            //iterating through all the values in database
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);

                uploads.add(0, upload);


            }





            //creating adapter
            adapter = new MyAdaptador(getApplicationContext(), uploads);


            //adding adapter to recyclerview
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);




        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });





}
}
```

Comment: Cual es el proposito del texto que debe ignorar? Si no tiene ningún proposito, no sería mejor quitarlo de la pregunta?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que me dice que tengo demasiado código y lo uso el Lorem para rellenar.

Comment: Ya veo! Gracias por la aclaración!

Comment: cuando te sale ese mensaje quiere decir que lo más probable es que necesites más texto para poder explicar tu problema, eso ayuda a que tengas más respuestas de calidad, por ello te sugiero agregar un ejemplo en que se vea que tipo de datos quieres pasar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que podrías hacer es agregar un `setOnClickListener` a la vista del `item` que pertenece a tu `recyclerView`, tal que así:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {...});
```

Dentro de las llaves, inicializas un objeto de tipo Intent. Así:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(holder.itemView.getContext(), [La actividad a la que quieres ir].class);
```

A ese `intent` le agregas los argumentos que quieres pasar con el método `putExtra();`

```
intent.putExtra([KEY], [El valor]);
```

Y luego haces llamar el método `startActivity`, por ejemplo:

```
holder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

De esta manera puedes pasar datos de acuerdo al `item` *clickeado* de tu `recyclerView`. Es un ejemplo de varios que puedes encontrar por Internet. A mí me funcionó. Espero que también te funcione.